# How to survive a database outage?

Tags: web-services, database-connection, c3p0

I have a web service that is made using spring, hibernate and c3p0. I also have a service wide cache(which has the results of requests ever made to the service) which can be used to return results when the service isn't able to return(due to whatever reason). The cache might return stale results when the database is out but that's ok.

I recently faced a database outage and my service came to a crashing halt. 
I want the clients of my service to survive database outages happening ever again in future.

For that, I need my service to:

1. Handle new incoming requests like this: quickly say that the database is down and throw some exception(fast-fail).
2. Requests already being processed: Don't last longer than x seconds. How do I make the thread handling the request be interrupted somehow.
3. Cache the whole database in memory for read-only purposes(Is this insane?).

There are some observations that I made:

1. If there is one or more connection(s) with status ESTABLISHED, then an attempt to checkout a new connection is not made. Seems like any one connection with status ESTABLISED is handed over to the thread receiving the request. Now, this thread just hangs till the time the database comes back up.
   I would want to make this request fast-fail by knowing before handling over a connection to a thread whether db is up or not. If no, the service should throw exception instead of hanging up.
2. If there's no connection with status ESTABLISHED, then the request fails in 10 secs with the exception that "Could not checkout a new connection". This is due to my checkout timeout being set for 10s.
3. If the service was processing some request, now the db goes and then the service makes a call to db, the thread making the call to db gets stuck forever. It resumes execution only after the db comes back.
   I would like to interrupt the thread after say x seconds whether or not it was able to complete the request.

Are there ways to accomplish what I seek?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "How do I make the thread handling the request be interrupted somehow." With c3p0 you can use the [unreturnedConnectionTimeout](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#unreturnedConnectionTimeout) parameter to do this.

Comment: unreturnedConnectionTimeout wouldn't help. This is what I observed with it:
If the service did a get from db just after the db went down, the thread was just stuck there till the time db came back up. Once the db is back up, the get finishes. If it is now deducted that this connection has been held for more than unreturnedConnectionTimeout, then an exception is raised.